# Efficiently load and manipulate csv using dask DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I am trying to manipulate the csv-file from https://www.kaggle.com/raymondsunartio/6000-nasdaq-stocks-historical-daily-prices using `dask.dataframe`. The original dataframe has columns **'date', 'ticker', 'open', 'close',** etc...

My goal is to create a new data frame with index **'date'** and columns as the closing price of each unique ticker.

The following code does the trick, but is quite slow, using almost a minute for `N = 6`. I suspect that dask tries to read the CSV-file multiple times in the for-loop, but **I don't know how I would go about making this faster.** My initial guess is that using `df.groupby('ticker')` somewhere would help, but I am not familiar enough with pandas.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
from functools import reduce

def load_and_fix_csv(path: str, N: int, tickers: list = None) -> dd.DataFrame:
    raw = dd.read_csv(path, parse_dates=["date"])
    if tickers is None:
        tickers = raw.ticker.unique().compute()[:N] # Get unique tickers
    dfs = []
    for tick in tickers:
        tmp = raw[raw.ticker == tick][["date", "close"]] # Temporary dataframe from specific ticker with columns date, close
        dfs.append(tmp)
    df = reduce(lambda x, y: dd.merge(x, y, how="outer", on="date"), dfs) # Merge all dataframes on date
    df = df.set_index("date").compute()
    return df
```

Every kind of help is appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're right that Dask is likely going "back to the well" for each loop; this is because Dask builds a graph of operations and attempts to defer computation until forced or necessary. One thing I like to do is to cut the reading operations of the graph with `Client.persist`:

```py
from distributed import Client

client = Client()


def persist_load_and_fix_csv(path: str, N: int, tickers: list = None) -> dd.DataFrame:
    raw = dd.read_csv(path, parse_dates=["date"])

    # This "cuts the graph" prior operations (just the `read_csv` here)
    raw = client.persist(raw)
    if tickers is None:
        tickers = raw.ticker.unique().compute()[:N] # Get unique tickers
    dfs = []
    for tick in tickers:
        tmp = raw[raw.ticker == tick][["date", "close"]] # Temporary dataframe from specific ticker with columns date, close
        dfs.append(tmp)
    df = reduce(lambda x, y: dd.merge(x, y, how="outer", on="date"), dfs) # Merge all dataframes on date
    df = df.set_index("date").compute()
    return df
```

In a Kaggle session I tested both functions with `persist_load_and_fix_csv(csv_path, N=3)` and managed to cut the time in half. You'll also get better performance by only keeping the columns you end up using.

(*Note: I've found that, at least for me and my code, if I start seeing `.compute()` crop up in functions that I should step back and reevaluate the code paths; I view it as a code smell*)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this! By "keeping the columns I end  up using", do you mean while reading the csv-file?

Comment: Sure it could be done at that point, basically try not to lock up memory with data that you won't end up using -- at least drop the column before the `client.persist`